# Find single color, horizontal spaces in image

Tags: python, opencv

For example, there might be a table with text in rows. How could I find all straight, horizontal lines going through the table? E.g. (red lines are the found lines):

[image]

Comment: This is my result using `morph-op` :https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysGA.png

Comment: A simple color segmentation using `cv2.inRange()` would work well here

Comment: Is the color of the line always the same?

Comment: @Silencer that is the correct answer, you should write it as an answer for completeness :)

Comment: @api55 Ok, I'll write the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `for this question`, to detect the `horizontal lines`, the `morph-op` is enough.

```
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((1,100), np.uint8)
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("res", morphed);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

---

Update, similar questions:

(1) [Find single color, horizontal spaces in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667238/find-single-color-horizontal-spaces-in-image/47675213#47675213)

(2) [OpenCV/cv2: Removing horizontal underlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327567/opencv-cv2-removing-horizontal-underlines/48365071#48365071)